# Nil in OpenWeather API

Tags: ios, swift, api, nsurlsession

I've just started to learn `Swift` and `iOS` and I have problem in my weather app. I'm trying to get weather data and print in console, but there is still nil and I no have idea what could be wrong. I tried to change the model, pasted all url and is still nil. Sometimes app sends data and there is no answer, but at other times is answer or no sending, no answer. In console always nil...

**Generated model class**:

```
    import Foundation

    class CurrentWeather : NSObject, NSCoding{


    var base : String!
    var clouds : Cloud!
    var cod : Int!
    var coord : Coord!
    var dt : Int!
    var id : Int!
    var main : Main!
    var name : String!
    var sys : Sy!
    var visibility : Int!
    var weather : [Weather]!
    var wind : Wind!


    /**
     * Instantiate the instance using the passed dictionary values to set the properties values
     */
    init(fromDictionary dictionary: [String:Any]){
        base = dictionary["base"] as? String
        cod = dictionary["cod"] as? Int
        dt = dictionary["dt"] as? Int
        id = dictionary["id"] as? Int
        name = dictionary["name"] as? String
        visibility = dictionary["visibility"] as? Int
        if let cloudsData = dictionary["clouds"] as? [String:Any]{
            clouds = Cloud(fromDictionary: cloudsData)
        }
        if let coordData = dictionary["coord"] as? [String:Any]{
            coord = Coord(fromDictionary: coordData)
        }
        if let mainData = dictionary["main"] as? [String:Any]{
            main = Main(fromDictionary: mainData)
        }
        if let sysData = dictionary["sys"] as? [String:Any]{
            sys = Sy(fromDictionary: sysData)
        }
        if let windData = dictionary["wind"] as? [String:Any]{
            wind = Wind(fromDictionary: windData)
        }
        weather = [Weather]()
        if let weatherArray = dictionary["weather"] as? [[String:Any]]{
            for dic in weatherArray{
                let value = Weather(fromDictionary: dic)
                weather.append(value)
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns all the available property values in the form of [String:Any] object where the key is the approperiate json key and the value is the value of the corresponding property
     */
    func toDictionary() -> [String:Any]
    {
        var dictionary = [String:Any]()
        if base != nil{
            dictionary["base"] = base
        }
        if cod != nil{
            dictionary["cod"] = cod
        }
        if dt != nil{
            dictionary["dt"] = dt
        }
        if id != nil{
            dictionary["id"] = id
        }
        if name != nil{
            dictionary["name"] = name
        }
        if visibility != nil{
            dictionary["visibility"] = visibility
        }
        if clouds != nil{
            dictionary["clouds"] = clouds.toDictionary()
        }
        if coord != nil{
            dictionary["coord"] = coord.toDictionary()
        }
        if main != nil{
            dictionary["main"] = main.toDictionary()
        }
        if sys != nil{
            dictionary["sys"] = sys.toDictionary()
        }
        if wind != nil{
            dictionary["wind"] = wind.toDictionary()
        }
        if weather != nil{
            var dictionaryElements = [[String:Any]]()
            for weatherElement in weather {
                dictionaryElements.append(weatherElement.toDictionary())
            }
            dictionary["weather"] = dictionaryElements
        }
        return dictionary
    }

    /**
     * NSCoding required initializer.
     * Fills the data from the passed decoder
     */
    @objc required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
    {
        base = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "base") as? String
        clouds = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "clouds") as? Cloud
        cod = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "cod") as? Int
        coord = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "coord") as? Coord
        dt = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "dt") as? Int
        id = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "id") as? Int
        main = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "main") as? Main
        name = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "name") as? String
        sys = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "sys") as? Sy
        visibility = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "visibility") as? Int
        weather = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "weather") as? [Weather]
        wind = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "wind") as? Wind
    }

    /**
     * NSCoding required method.
     * Encodes mode properties into the decoder
     */
    @objc func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder)
    {
        if base != nil{
            aCoder.encode(base, forKey: "base")
        }
        if clouds != nil{
            aCoder.encode(clouds, forKey: "clouds")
        }
        if cod != nil{
            aCoder.encode(cod, forKey: "cod")
        }
        if coord != nil{
            aCoder.encode(coord, forKey: "coord")
        }
        if dt != nil{
            aCoder.encode(dt, forKey: "dt")
        }
        if id != nil{
            aCoder.encode(id, forKey: "id")
        }
        if main != nil{
            aCoder.encode(main, forKey: "main")
        }
        if name != nil{
            aCoder.encode(name, forKey: "name")
        }
        if sys != nil{
            aCoder.encode(sys, forKey: "sys")
        }
        if visibility != nil{
            aCoder.encode(visibility, forKey: "visibility")
        }
        if weather != nil{
            aCoder.encode(weather, forKey: "weather")
        }
        if wind != nil{
            aCoder.encode(wind, forKey: "wind")
        }
    }

}
```

**WeatherService:**

```
    import Foundation

    class WeatherSerice {

    let weatherAPIKey: String
    let weatherBaseURL: URL?

    init(APIKey: String) {

        self.weatherAPIKey = APIKey
        weatherBaseURL = URL(string: "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?")
    }

    func getCurrentWeather(city: String, completion: @escaping (CurrentWeather?) -> Void) {

        if let weatherURL = URL(string: "\(weatherBaseURL!)q=\(city)&appid=\(weatherAPIKey)") {

            let networkProcessor = NetworkProcessor(url: weatherURL)
            networkProcessor.downloadJSONFromURL({(jsonDictionary) in

            if let currentWeatherDictionary = jsonDictionary?["currently"] as?
                [String : Any] {
                let currentWeather = CurrentWeather(fromDictionary: currentWeatherDictionary)
                completion(currentWeather)
            } else {
                completion(nil)
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

**Part of the UIViewController**:

```
  let weatherService = WeatherSerice(APIKey: "52e6ff60bba8613b4850e065dcd3d0ac")
    weatherService.getCurrentWeather(city: "London") {
        (currentWeather) in

        print (currentWeather)
    }
```

Comment: Instead of implementing manual parsing, you can use `Codable` to create models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, please drop `NSCoding` in favor of `Codable`, you will get rid of all that ugly boilerplate code

```
struct WeatherData : Decodable {
    let coord : Coordinate
    let cod, visibility, id : Int
    let name : String
    let base : String
    let weather : [Weather]
    let clouds: Clouds
    let sys : Sys
    let main : Main
    let wind : Wind
    let dt : Date
}

struct Coordinate : Decodable {
    let lat, lon : Double
}

struct Weather : Decodable {
    let id : Int
    let icon : String
    let main : MainEnum
    let description: String
}

struct Sys : Decodable {
    let type, id : Int
    let sunrise, sunset : Date
    let message : Double
    let country : String
}

struct Main : Decodable {
    let temp, tempMin, tempMax : Double
    let pressure, humidity : Int
}

struct Wind : Decodable {
    let speed : Double
    let deg : Int
    let gust : Double?
}

struct Clouds: Decodable {
    let all: Int
}

enum MainEnum: String, Decodable {
    case clear = "Clear"
    case clouds = "Clouds"
    case rain = "Rain"
}
```

As you can see the dates are decoded as `Date` and the `main` values in `Weather` are decoded as enum.

---

I don't know the API `NetworkProcessor` so I replaced it with traditional `URLSession`. The added `URLComponents` provide proper URL encoding for example if the `city` contains space characters

```
import Foundation

class WeatherSerice {

    let weatherAPIKey: String
    let weatherBase = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather"

    init(APIKey: String) {

        self.weatherAPIKey = APIKey
    }

    func getCurrentWeather(city: String, completion: @escaping (WeatherData?) -> Void) {

        var urlComponents = URLComponents(string: weatherBase)!
        let queryItems = [URLQueryItem(name: "q", value: city),
                         URLQueryItem(name: "appid", value: weatherAPIKey)]                     
        urlComponents.queryItems = queryItems

        if let weatherURL = urlComponents.url {

            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: weatherURL) { (data, response, error) in

                if let error = error { print(error); completion(nil) }

                do {
                    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                    decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
                    decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .secondsSince1970
                    let result = try decoder.decode(WeatherData.self, from: data!)
                    completion(result)  
                } catch { 
                    print(error)
                    completion(nil)
                }       
            }
            task.resume()
        }
    }
}
```

I recommend to use the new `Result` type in Swift 5 to return the error, too.

```
    func getCurrentWeather(city: String, completion: @escaping (Result<WeatherData,Error>) -> Void) {

        var urlComponents = URLComponents(string: weatherBase)!
        let queryItems = [URLQueryItem(name: "q", value: city),
                         URLQueryItem(name: "appid", value: weatherAPIKey)]                     
        urlComponents.queryItems = queryItems

        if let weatherURL = urlComponents.url {

            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: weatherURL) { (data, response, error) in

                if let error = error { completion(.failure(error)) }

                do {
                    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                    decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
                    decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .secondsSince1970
                    let result = try decoder.decode(WeatherData.self, from: data!)
                    completion(.success(result))
                } catch { 
                    completion(.failure(error))
                }       
            }
            task.resume()
        }
```

and use it

```
weatherService.getCurrentWeather(city: "London") { result in
    switch result {
    case .success(let result): print(result)
    case .failure(let error): print(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution and I have this: Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value in weatherService.getCurrentWaether

Comment: Where, in which line? I tested the code successfully.

Comment: Ok, the application does not crashing, but the all values are nil. App sending and receiving data. Even more than before and every time I use it

Comment: The values cannot be `nil` as all struct members (except one) are non-optional. Either you get the data or you get an error. As I said I tested the code with my API key and it worked flawlessly.

Comment: This is what I have in console:
keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "cloud", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"cloud\", intValue: nil) (\"cloud\").", underlyingError: nil))
keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "cloud", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"cloud\", intValue: nil) (\"cloud\").", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: Please use my structs. They work. It's `clouds` not `cloud`

Comment: It works! So strange. I used separated structs and it didn't works, but now is fine.
Great! Thank you so much Swift Wizard!